# What should be the title for this problem?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, titles

While reading the general solutions of trigonometric equations, I came to this:

> The equation $\sin\theta = k$ is satisfied by two values of $\theta$  of the form $\alpha$ & $\pi - \alpha$ in the interval $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ .

Ok. But when I read the result for $\cos\theta = k$, the interval was given $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ .

Now, I want to know what is the cause for the different intervals. Can't they be same? I want to post this but not getting any proper title. Can anyone please suggest me a good title which portrays my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd go along the lines of one of the following:

- Codomains of inverse sine and cosine
- Description of preimages of values of sine and cosine
- Describing solutions to $\sin \theta = k$ and $\cos \theta = k$